# DataGridView retrieve checked row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

The thing is that I have `DataGridView1`, when I click on it I store some values and after clicking on `*edit*` button new window opens and I retrieve all info from that selected row cells.
But, when I turn off that window I set the code to automatically refresh my `DGV1`, what I need is after refreshing to retrieve that previously checked row and get it again so my client can easily continue working since they have like 10.000 rows so they don't want to search for next row everytime when they edit something.

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting the point properly (some code/pic might help): you are saying that if you select row 250, a popup comes up, you perform any actions on it and, right after closing the popup, the DGV is refreshed. Because of this "refresh" the given row 250 is not displayed anymore, but row 1. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Exactly that's what I am saying. The thing is that I have to refresh that DGV, so basically I have to set the value of selected row and after refreshing I have to call thay value of selected row again. I just need code example for that.

Comment: But I did a quick test and this does not seem to be the default behaviour of DataGridView: after refreshing it, the last selected row remains. Could you please paste here the part of your code where this behaviour happens? (when you close the popup and refresh the datagridview)

Comment: I am refreshing DGV programatically, which means after editing values in new form I call stored procedure to fill my DGV

Comment: Ah! you are refilling the DGV, I thought that you were just using the Refresh() method. OK, this is a different story. Will write a reply right now.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry if I confused you with some statements.

Comment: No problem. There you have my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are retrieving the current Row/Column indices, but I am writing a code triggered from the `CellClick Event` which you shouldn't find any problem to adapt to your specific requirements:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim selectedRow As Integer = e.RowIndex
    Dim selectedCol As Integer = e.ColumnIndex
    fillDataGridView()

    DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = DataGridView1(selectedCol, selectedRow)
End Sub
```

Where `fillDataGridView()` performs the refilling.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa What I meant is that the code DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = DataGridView1(selectedCol, selectedRow) needs to know the row and column indices which you want to show. I don't know how you code deals with this information and that's why I just relied on the CellClick event as an example. What you have to do is populate both variables selectedRow and selectedCol with the right information (by whatever means you want); perform the refilling and, after this process is completed, use the code DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell, etc.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa I can advise you further if you show me the part of the code from where you are callning 'DataManager.DataBaseLayer.NapuniDtSQLProc. The code you wrote is useless because is working just on your application; post a DataGridView1 related method from where you call this part if you want further help. In any case, you should be able to do by your own: how do you know what are the currently-selected row/column? This is the whole point.

Comment: Yes, I need this `CellClick` event, but can I use the last row of event code `DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = DataGridView1(selectedCol, selectedRow)` in code of new form? Since I perform refilling from that window `DataManager.DataBaseLayer.NapuniDtSQLProc("SIN_OkruziSelect", Me.Tabela)` where `NapuniDtSQLProc` is `Public Shared Function NapuniDtSQLProc(ByVal SProcedura As String, ByVal tabela As System.Data.DataTable) As System.Data.DataTable`

Comment: I think I got it now, yes I defined both variable `selectedRow` and `selectedCol` and I succeded to do what I needed.  Thank you very much for you help.